# Apps Script - Creating new doc on form submission failing and creating new blank pdf instead

Tags: exception, google-apps-script, eventtrigger

The following code is supposed to gather the responses from a submitted google form, and create a google doc and add them to it within a target folder. The code uses a trigger that activates on a form submission. However, it is currently only creating blank pdf files when the forum is submitted, what is the problem? The createTrigger function is what I used to create the trigger that runs the code on a form submission. I've messed with this for a long time but I only ever get it to create blank pdfs instead of google docs with the form data. I'm a way beginner at this stuff and really only messed with python, so take it with grain of salt.

```
    function onFormSubmitTrigger() {
      var formResponse = getLastFormResponse();
      createDocFromFormResponse(formResponse);
    }

    function getLastFormResponse() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastRowValues = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
      return lastRowValues;
    }

    function createDocFromFormResponse(formResponse) {
      var folderName = "Spa Job Log Repository";

      var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Spa Job Log Repository");

      var targetFolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();

      if (targetFolder) {
        var newDoc = DocumentApp.create("Form Response Document");
        var newDocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId());
        targetFolder.createFile(newDocFile);

        var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newDoc.getId());
        var body = doc.getBody();

        for (var i = 0; i < formResponse.length; i++) {
          body.appendParagraph("Response " + (i + 1) + ": " + formResponse[i]);
        }

        doc.saveAndClose();
      } else {
        Logger.log("Folder '" + folderName + "' not found.");
      }
    }

    function createTrigger() {
      var form = FormApp.openById('1jGAWZXcOHOfbM1uk88QMBg-yl4VdSHxynRM-NHawASQ');
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmitTrigger')
        .forForm(form)
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();
    }
```

The createTrigger function is what I used to create the trigger that runs the code on a form submission. I've messed with this for a long time but I only ever get it to create blank pdfs instead of google docs with the form data. I'm a way beginner at this stuff and really only messed with python, so take it with grain of salt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a new Google Document and want to put the created Document to `targetFolder`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that a Google Document is created in the root folder. But, by `targetFolder.createFile(newDocFile);`, the created Document is converted to PDF format and the PDF file is put to `targetFolder`. In the current stage, when Google Docs files (Document, Spreadsheet, Slide) are created by `createFile`, the mimeType is automatically converted to PDF. I guessed that this is the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the function `createDocFromFormResponse` is modified.

```js
function createDocFromFormResponse(formResponse) {
  var folderName = "Spa Job Log Repository";

  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("###"); // Please set your folder ID.

  var targetFolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  if (targetFolder) {
    var newDoc = DocumentApp.create("Form Response Document");
    var newDocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId());
    newDocFile.moveTo(targetFolder);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newDoc.getId());
    var body = doc.getBody();
    for (var i = 0; i < formResponse.length; i++) {
      body.appendParagraph("Response " + (i + 1) + ": " + formResponse[i]);
    }
    doc.saveAndClose();
    // targetFolder.createFile(doc.getBlob()); // If you want to also create a PDF file into "targetFolder", please use this line.
  } else {
    Logger.log("Folder '" + folderName + "' not found.");
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, at `var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("Spa Job Log Repository");`, if you use the folder name to `getFolderById`, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)